# One thread receiving another thread result

Tags: process, sockets, multithreading

I have a thread poo where I am creating 10 threads. Those threads are used to fetch data between two different process (`Process A is on local machine and Process B on server`) via a `socket`.

When I am running my code I observe that the result I am expecting from `thread 1` I am getting on `thread 4`, It is swapping it always.

I want to know how can I stop this swapping?

For distinction between thread I am using `pthread_key_create()` and for maintaining threads I am using `pthread_setspecific()`

Comment: I don't think there's a way to answer this without the code.

Comment: Sounds like both threads are using the same socket handle when they shouldn't be.